# Performing nvidia gpu scaling on ffmpeg desktop captured using ddagrab (on Windows)

Tags: ffmpeg, video, gpu, nvenc

Looking for some advice on how to combine options relating to screen grabbing with ddagrab using ffmpeg, encoding using nvenc and scaling down in the process.

I can successfully capture desktop to file without scaling using nvenc, and I can also decode a file, scale it it and re-encode using nvenc. However putting the two together is giving me an error.

The command I am using is :

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel_output_format cuda -f lavfi -i ddagrab -vf scale_cuda=w=960:h=540 -c:v h264_nvenc -cq:v 21 c:\temp\test.mp4
```

And the error I get is:

```
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream: 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
```

I see other reports of this error on google which suggest lots of additional options, but no clear examples of how to do a desktop capture, scale and encode before it leaves the gpu and comes back to the cpu.

I am using ffmeg 6.1.1 x64 binaries compiled with enable-cuda-llvm on Win11.

Comment: It's not working because the output pixel format of `ddagrab` is `d3d11` (and not `cuda`). `h264_nvenc` encoder accepts `d3d11` as input pixel format. `scale_cuda` filter doesn't accept `d3d11` as input. It looks like there is no direct conversion from `d3d11` to `cuda` format. There is also no `scale_d3d11` filter. Download and upload is working, but inefficient: `fmpeg -y -f lavfi -i ddagrab -vf hwdownload,format=bgra,format=yuv444p,hwupload_cuda,scale_cuda=w=960:h=540:format=yuv444p -c:v h264_nvenc -cq:v 21 -t 3 test.mkv`

Comment: Thanks for that @Rotem, what I like about that is that it's only the px format conversion being done cpu-side and not the whole re-scale. Obviously it's a lot of traffic hitting the bus though.  (I'm testing this using an 8K desktop size).  It surprises me that scale_cuda does not handle that input format.  I suppose the only other way to go with this is to get ddagrab in ffpmeg enhanced to do the rescale in directx without it leaving the gpu - fairly sure that should be possible.

Comment: One more thing - assuming I'm not doing any scaling at all, and just going straight from ddagrab to encoded hevc video, how to specify pixel format yuv444p ?  It defaults to yuv420 so that conversion is happening somewhere in the gpu. Can nvenc not go from d3d11 to anything "better" than yuv420?

Comment: For encoding yuv444p, add `-profile:v high444p` argument. The d3d11 pixel format is probably `bgra` (by default, the `h264_nvenc` encoder converts the format to yuv420). d3d11 filtering is [marked](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro) as "Not yet integrated, but work is being done in this area.". d3d11 scaling is technically possible, but not yet supported by FFmpeg.

Comment: Would you mind listing what options you would use to do the same thing in hevc? (As in a full working example of grabbing from ddagrab (unscaled) and encoding to a high qual yuv444 file.  Ta

Comment: Replace the encoder from `h264_nvenc` to `hevc_nvenc`: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i ddagrab -vf hwdownload,format=bgra,format=yuv444p,hwupload_cuda,scale_cuda=w=960:h=540:format=yuv444p -c:v hevc_nvenc -cq:v 21 -t 3 test.mkv`. (I don't know if `-cq:v 21` is the best option). For best speed, I suggest you to benchmark `ddagrab` against `gdigrab` and `dshow` as shown [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop#Windows). You may also try defining large buffer for real-time frames: `-rtbufsize 300M`.